# How to /summon a skeleton with a dyed armor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I, with the `summon` command, summon a skeleton with a full red-dyed leather armor and a name?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
/summon Skeleton ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"NameTag",ArmorItems:[{id:"minecraft:leather_boots",tag:{display:{color:16711680}}},{id:"minecraft:leather_leggings",tag:{display:{color:16711680}}},{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",tag:{display:{color:16711680}}},{id:"minecraft:leather_helmet",tag:{display:{color:16711680}}}]##}
```

If you want the skeleton to hold anything, replace the `##` at the end with `,HandItems:[`[Item Tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Item_structure)`]`. Otherwise, remove it.

I’ve tested this, and it seems to work. If you encounter any problems, please comment and I will look into it further.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes I encountered a problem: the command block says that there is an unbalanced curly bracket...

Comment: are you sure you copied it correctly? it's too long for the chat; you have to use a command block.

Comment: Yes, I used a command block, but it don't works.

Comment: @Kimatuy You're sure you copied it correctly? You removed the ##? You're playing on 1.9?